# WPF Application Command Bindings doesn't work

Tags: wpf, routed-commands, commandbinding, routedevent

Hi
I have a strange problem with CommandBindings in WPF. 
I add CommandBindings in constructor of object. The command bindings looks like that

```
   CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Copy,Copy_Executed,Copy_Enabled));
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Cut,Cut_Executed,Cut_Enabled));
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Paste,Paste_Executed,Paste_Enabled));
```

Coresponding functions which are responsible for execution look that way

```
 private void Paste_Enabled(object sender,CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = selectionService != null && selectionService.CurrentSelection.Count > 0;

    }

    private void Paste_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            if (GetSelected() != null)
                Paste(true);
            else
               Paste(false);

    }



    private void Copy_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Copy();
    }

    private void Copy_Enabled(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = selectionService.CurrentSelection.OfType<DesignerItem>().Count() > 0;
    }

    #endregion
private void Cut_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Copy();
        DeleteCurrentSelection(false);
    }

    private void Cut_Enabled(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = this.SelectionService.CurrentSelection.Count() > 0;
    }
```

The problem is that only cut command works. I mean if I set a breakpoint in any other funciotn (copy or paste) the breakpoint are not hit. Could somebody tell me what I do wrong ??

Comment: Does the code get to the Copy_Enabled method?

Answer (score 0):

Are `Copy` and `Paste` commands bound to any control in your application window? Looks like the `UI` only looks for `Cut` command and not other two commands. Make sure you bound other two commands to the `UI` well.

Comment: I dont' bount this command to any other control. I just make the bounding in class

Answer (score 0):

You need to add KeyGestures also

```
  InputBindings.Add(new InputBinding("YourCommand" ,ApplicationCommands.Copy.InputGestures[0])) // Default Gesture is Ctrl+C
```